# The identity workflow intput option phone number list specified is empty

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to create and send an envelope using a DocuSign Template and In Person Signing with SMS Verification. I'm able to send an envelope using regular recipient signers, but having trouble with the Template/In Person Signers combination. I'm getting this response with my request:

```
{
    "errorCode" : "IDENTITY_WORKFLOW_INVALID_INPUTOPTION_EMPTY_PHONE_NUMBER_LIST",
    "message" : "The identity workflow intput option phone number list specified is empty."
}
```

Here's the JSON for my envelope that I'm sending:

```
    {
    "disableResponsiveDocument" : false,
    "emailBlurb" : "",
    "emailSubject" : "Please DocuSign Company Agreement",
    "recipients" : 
    {
        "carbonCopies" : []
    },
    "status" : "sent",
    "templateId" : "xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxx",
    "templateRoles" : 
    [
        {
            "hostEmail" : "host@acmetrading.com",
            "hostName" : "John Simpson",
            "identityVerification" : 
            {
                "inputOptions" : 
                [
                    {
                        "name" : "phone_number_list",
                        "phoneNumberList" : 
                        [
                            {
                                "countryCode" : "61",
                                "number" : "0412 345 678"
                            }
                        ],
                        "valueType" : "PhoneNumberList"
                    }
                ],
                "steps" : null,
                "workflowId" : "xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxx"
            },
            "inPersonSignerName" : "Jenny Jones",
            "roleName" : "Customer",
            "routingOrder" : "1",
            "tabs" : {}
        }
    ]
}
```

I've followed the [instructions for phone authentication](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/phone-auth/) and the same code works for regular signers so not sure what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phone numbers cannot include spaces

**0412 345 678 - is bad**

**0412345678 is good**

(BTW, if this is your real number, you got an SMS from DocuSign - that was me trying it)

Comment: I've removed the spaces and still getting the same error. I've sent requests successfully with spaces before using regular singers, so don't think that is the issue here? p.s. that is not my real number, just a made up one.

Comment: I confirmed by trying with spaces - got your error and then removed spaces and didn't get the error